# Bundle and build libcurl along with custom lib

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

### Problem

How can I distribute a c++ library as source code along with the source code of libcurl and let the consumer of the library handle building it as needed? I'm using FastBuild as a build system.

### Context

I have a C++ library that I distribute as source and let the clients handle building it along with their code.

The repo includes the source for a dependency as well, tinyxml, which is built along with the library itself thus becoming completely transparent for the clients.

It has worked fine up to now but clearly does not scale well for more complex dependencies, such as libcurl.

#### Things I've considered as an alternative to bundling libcurl's source

- have pre-compiled libraries of libcurl. But I don't know which platforms/flags the consumer is going to use
- have libcurl installed on the build machine. It would require extra setup steps for the consumer, it won't be just pulling the code and using

Edit 1: Update with build system

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which build system are you using.
If you are using `cmake`, you can make use of `ExternalProject_Add` to download/build/install the dependent library.

See examples:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/module/ExternalProject.html#examples

Comment: I'm using FastBuild as a build system., Using cmake would really make thing easier.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need that any client who obtains source code of your library would be able to also obtain corresponding source code of `libcurl` and `tinyxml` libraries.
Personally I would use `cmake` for that purpose as @brokenfoot has already suggested. But instead of `ExternalProject_Add` it seems that in your case `FetchContent` would be enough and less complicated: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html

Comment: I'm using FastBuild as a build system., Using cmake would really make thing easier.

Comment: @andreferreirav2 i have tried to build test lib for Mac OS which depends on `libcurl` using `cmake` but it seems that `curl` project is not ready for using with `cmake` `FetchContent` module out of the box. So I'have used `FetchContent` only to get `curl` sources corresponding to particular commit and then call shell script from inside `cmake` that use autotools to build `curl`